# Where is the problem?Workspace switching during bricscad drafting with zooming with mouse wheel!

Tags: 12.04, cad

Well, i am currently working with bricscad v12 for my 2D drawings, BUT i have a very annoying issue. When i am zooming too much in brics and working with an active command the workspace is changing. So, how can i figure out where exactly is the problem?

I tried to find something in google but no one mentions something about it!So, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you pressing any combination of Ctrl+Alt+Arrow or Super(Windows key)+Arrow while working, even if by accident? Or does this program synthesize those combinations of events by any chance?

You can change the keybindings use for switching workspaces, under `System Settings->Keyboard`, or just stop pressing those keys. If the program is synthesizing the events somehow, you will probably need to change the keybindings as a workaround, and you should report a problem against that program, in it's issue tracking system.

Comment: well, i am not pressing any other keys than mouse clicks and wheel scroll up and down!?!So what should i do?thanks

Comment: You need to open an issue about your problem with Bricsys I presume.